# Side by side React components not displaying how I want

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working on a react-app website and I'm pretty new to this all.
The current look is this:
[image: Current]

There's a toggle button and a dropdown, and they are above each other. Both are from semantic-ui-react.  The code is here:

```
   <Segment>
       <LineChart
         ...
       </LineChart>
       <div >
         <div >
           <Checkbox
             toggle
             label="Full History"
             checked={fullHistory}
             onChange={() => { changeSettingsState({ fullHistory: !fullHistory }); }}
           />
         </div>
         <div>
           <Dropdown placeholder='Select 2 Flight Data Options' fluid multiple selection options={options} value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.menuChange} />
         </div>
       </div>
     </Segment>
```

I want the button and dropdown to be side by side, filling the horizontal space together. That's why I've put them in divs. I tried using style={{float:'left'}} and style={{float:'right'}} in the divs that  contain Checkbox and Dropdown but that results in the following that bursts out of the box and looks bad. [image: this mess]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say for sure if this will work since there's no way to try the code, but this *should* do the job:

```
<div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
  <Checkbox
             toggle
             label="Full History"
             checked={fullHistory}
             onChange={() => { changeSettingsState({ fullHistory: !fullHistory }); }}
  />
   <Dropdown placeholder='Select 2 Flight Data Options' fluid multiple selection options={options} value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.menuChange} />         
</div>
```

Note that the `div` wrappers around `Checkbox` and `Dropdown` are removed since they're unnecessary with this solution.

Comment: Almost: https://imgur.com/Wr076XO The text is a little bit blocked.

Comment: Can you provide a CodeSandbox or something like that to experiment with?

Comment: I couldn't get the style right but here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ngw7u?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hmm -- for me, the Checkbox and Dropdown don't actually load how they look in your example, so I can't test anything related to layout

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant by the style, I'm not sure how to make them look correct, none of the css files seem to be altered my project and I inherited the code from someone else. I'll just keep trying things, thanks for your help